# secondary column shifts on click + three dots shouldn't be a bullet

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to figure out how to get the 3 dots to not be a bullet. I don't want to hide the bullet either because it will show as a gap in my bulleted list as it does when you click the show more button and makes the list uneven. I don't know much JavaScript so I'm not sure how to work around this problem.

```html
 <head>
 <script> 
    function myFunction() {
     var dots = document.getElementById("dots");
    var btnText = document.getElementById("myBtn");
    var more = document.querySelectorAll(".more");

    if (dots.style.display === "none") {
    more.forEach(el => el.classList.add("hidden"));
    dots.style.display = "inline";
    btnText.innerHTML = "Read more";
    } else {
    more.forEach(el => el.classList.remove("hidden"));
    dots.style.display = "none";
    btnText.innerHTML = "Read less";
    }
    }
    </script>
    <style>
    #more {
      display: none;
    }

    .columns {
    columns: 2;
    -webkit-columns: 2;
    -moz-columns: 2;
    position: relative;
    }

    .hed {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 800;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 15px 0px 5px;
    }

    .hidden {
    display: none;
    } 
 
    table.map-list td{
 width:50% !important;
 vertical-align: top !important;
 }
 
    </style>
 
 </head>

    <body>

    <table class="map-list" width="100%" border="0">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <h4>Elementary</h4>
          <ul>
            <li>Maps: Primary: ELS</li>
            <li>Maps: Primary: Readiness</li>
            <li><span id="dots">...</span></li>
     <li class="more hidden">U.S. History:8 Revolutionary 
    War</li>
          </ul>
        </td>

        <td>
          <h4>Secondary</h4>
          <ul>
            <li>Maps: Intermediate: Physical</li>
            <li>Maps: Intermediate: Political</li>
                     <li class="more hidden">Maps: Secondary: Population 
    Thematic</li>

          </ul>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    <button onclick="myFunction()" id="myBtn">Read more</button>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing the parent `<li>` element for `dots` span would fix that issue.

```
<span id="dots">...</span>
```

**Live Example:**

```html
<head>
 <script> 
    function myFunction() {
     var dots = document.getElementById("dots");
    var btnText = document.getElementById("myBtn");
    var more = document.querySelectorAll(".more");

    if (dots.style.display === "none") {
    more.forEach(el => el.classList.add("hidden"));
    dots.style.display = "inline";
    btnText.innerHTML = "Read more";
    } else {
    more.forEach(el => el.classList.remove("hidden"));
    dots.style.display = "none";
    btnText.innerHTML = "Read less";
    }
    }
    </script>
    <style>
    #more {
      display: none;
    }

    .columns {
    columns: 2;
    -webkit-columns: 2;
    -moz-columns: 2;
    position: relative;
    }

    .hed {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 800;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 15px 0px 5px;
    }

    .hidden {
    display: none;
    } 
 
    table.map-list td{
 width:50% !important;
 vertical-align: top !important;
 }
 
    </style>
 
 </head>

    <body>

    <table class="map-list" width="100%" border="0">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <h4>Elementary</h4>
          <ul>
            <li>Maps: Primary: ELS</li>
            <li>Maps: Primary: Readiness</li>
            <span id="dots">...</span>
     <li class="more hidden">U.S. History:8 Revolutionary 
    War</li>
          </ul>
        </td>

        <td>
          <h4>Secondary</h4>
          <ul>
            <li>Maps: Intermediate: Physical</li>
            <li>Maps: Intermediate: Political</li>
                     <li class="more hidden">Maps: Secondary: Population 
    Thematic</li>

          </ul>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    <button onclick="myFunction()" id="myBtn">Read more</button>
    </body>
```